# No difference seen between landscape and potrait print aspose

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

Below is the Java code :

```java
DocumentBuilder w_Bldr = new DocumentBuilder();
```

The below code is in for loop.
Even if `w_Bldr.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);` is specified outside loop the print is still the same for both the modes.

```java
w_Bldr.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE); 
// if landscape 
w_Bldr.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.PORTRAIT); 
// if portrait 
w_Bldr.getParagraphFormat().setKeepWithNext(true); 
w_Bldr.getParagraphFormat().setKeepTogether(true); 
w_Bldr.getRowFormat().setAllowBreakAcrossPages(false); 
w_Bldr.getRowFormat().setAllowAutoFit(false); 
w_Bldr.writeln();
```

Jars used : Aspose.Words.jdk15.jar
aspose-cells-2.5.1.jar

How can this be fixed so that the difference should be noticeable?

Tried setting the pageWidth.

```java
w_Bldr.getPageSetup().setPageWidth(200);
```

But no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Page orientation is defined per section in MS Word documents. So to change page orientation section break must be inserted. For example see the following code that produces document with two section, one with portrait page orientation and another with landscape orientation:

```java
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
        
builder.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.PORTRAIT);
builder.writeln("This is PORTRAIT");
        
// Insert section break and change page orientation.
builder.insertBreak(BreakType.SECTION_BREAK_NEW_PAGE);
builder.getPageSetup().setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
builder.writeln("This is PORTRAIT");
    
doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx");
```

Comment: So after adding this insert break property i am able to see the width difference.Is this the only difference?Like is it correct?

Comment: Landscape and portrait page orientations differ by swapped dimensions.